# Create table using select query in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a way to create a new table based on a SELECT query in SQL Server ?

I do not want to manually enter all the fields (the table should be auto generated based on the fields in the query).

I already tried :

```
CREATE TABLE new_table AS (SELECT * FROM ...);
```

but it did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to alias the columns in the select, but I would have to think your current query aliases the fields if they don't have name.

> ```
> select
>   *
> into #tempabc
> from (
>   Select 'a' [test]
>   union
>   Select 'b' [test]
> ) a
>
> select * from #tempabc
> ```

Comment: Thanks but both options involve declaring the field names in the Destination Table. Can this be automated ?

Comment: The first option didn't specify the columns. I had to alias the field in the select. Also, this question has drastically changed with regards to intent.

Comment: Thanks, I replaced the discrete values with a Select * query and it worked !

Answer (score 3):

You are using the wrong syntax for SQL Server. Instead, try:

```
SELECT * INTO new_table FROM old_table
```

Comment: Thanks but in this case there is no "old_table". I want to use a runtime SELECT query instead of the "old_table".

Comment: Same principle applies: `SELECT * INTO new_table FROM (/*some query*/) t;

Answer (score 3):

```
CREATE TABLE NEW_TABLE
AS
SELECT employee_id, last_name,
FROM
employees
```

Comment: I do not want to manually enter all the fields (the table should be auto generated based on the fields in the query).

Answer (score 1):

you can proceed like this

```
select * into NewTable from  oldtable
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Maybe you could try like this in your query:

create table #temp(@field1 int,@field2 varchar(10))

insert into #temp

       select a,b from tableFrom



select * from #a
```

then, when you're not using the table again,

```
drop table #a
```

Comment: question is to create table instantly..not about inserting data into created table

Comment: @mohan111, your comment also applies to your own answer.  Adding "where 1=3" should solve that little issue.

Comment: Doesn't work...DROP Table CCC;

CREATE TABLE CCC AS (SELECT * FROM AAA); gives me the error Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.

Comment: The SELECT Query will Join multiple tables. This is the whole reason I need the Table to be created on the fly.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * INTO new_table FROM old_table where 1=2
```

where condition should be like your query should not return data

Comment: This didn't really address the question, but I didn't know you could create an empty table like that. Awesome to know. Thanks!